# What is wrong with my syntax on this if/else statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

I'm having an extremely frustrating error trying to code a simple encryption program on Python 2.7. Basically its rejecting on if/else statement by saying my syntax is invalid, and I have no idea what I did wrong. The : in the if input =="1": statement is what Python highlights as incorrect.

```
    #Main menu function, directs user to an operation
    def menu():
        input = raw_input("Type 1 for encryption, 2 for decryption, or 3 for information."
        if input == "1":
            print "Encryption selected..."
            encrypt()
        elif input == "2":
            print "Decryption selected..."
            decrypt()
        elif input == "3":
            print "Loading info..."
            info()
        else:
            print "ERROR: INVALID INPUT"
            menu()
```

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis on the raw_input line?

Comment: missed a closing paranthesis at the end of your raw_input() method.

Comment: Please don't name a variable `input`. `input` is a function, which can now no longer be used

Comment: input() is a function in Python 3, not Python 2, but point taken. I will use less generic variable names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket at the end of your `raw_input()` line?

Change

```
input = raw_input("Type 1 for encryption, 2 for decryption, or 3 for information."
```

to

```
input = raw_input("Type 1 for encryption, 2 for decryption, or 3 for information.")
```

Comment: Oh god, that is embarrassing.